# How to check if escape key has been pressed 3 times (like the trevor project website's safety)

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a website for people that feel their life is in danger or anything like that. I'm trying to recreate the [Trevor Project's](https://www.thetrevorproject.org/) escape key function with javascript.

I have some base code but it's not working:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

var escTime = 0;
function checkKeyPressed(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === "27") {
    window.clearTimeout();
    escTime++;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      escTime = 0;
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  if (escTime == 3) {
    window.location.replace("https://classroom.google.com/h");
    escTime = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: setTimeout() returns a unique value you need to pass to [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) in order to clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```js
function createCheckKeyPressFunction()
{
  let timeout;
  let escTime = 0;
  function checkKeyPressed(evt)
  {
    if (evt.key === "Escape")
    {
      console.log("Escape Detected");
      window.clearTimeout(timeout);
      escTime += 1;
      timeout = window.setTimeout(()=>
      {
        escTime = 0;
        console.log("Escape count reset to zero, due to timeout.");
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (escTime === 3) {
      let url = "https://classroom.google.com/h";
      console.log(url);
      window.location.replace(url);      
      escTime = 0;
    }
  }
  return checkKeyPressed;
 }
 let checkKeyPressed = createCheckKeyPressFunction();
 window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
```

```html
<p>Click to give this embedded snippet focus, and then test by hitting the ESC key.</p>
```

Since the code snippet (above) is embedded in this page, be sure to click into it after running it (to give it focus) before testing it with the `Esc` key.

Comment: Ok this worked perfectly before but now it's unreliable, only redirecting when you time the presses perfectly...

Comment: The way it is written, if more than one second passes before hitting the `ESC` key it resets. As long as you type the `ESC` key 3 times (without allowing a whole second to pass between presses) it should redirect on the 3rd press. Otherwise, it starts over counting the key presses. You can increase the delay allowed by changing 1000 to a larger number in the `setTimeout`.

Comment: That was my intention, and that does so work, but I do not believe that it is resetting each key press, and is instead just continuing the first keypress timeout.

Comment: Did you run the code snippet? Notice that if you hit `Esc` only once, the log notifies you of the timeout reset after 1 second. After that, it require 3 more presses (without allowing more than 1 second to elapse between those presses) to achieve the redirect.

Comment: Ah, I noticed I missed a line of code, it is now fixed! Thank you for being patient with me, and I'm sorry for leading you on this long!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're fairly close, but:

1. You have to remember the handle from `setTimeout` in order to cancel it, because you have to give it to `clearTimeout`.
2. `keyCode` is deprecated (though unlikely to actually go away), look at [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) instead.
3. There's no point in assigning `0` back to `escTime`, the treplace` leaves the page anyway.

So perhaps:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

let escapeTimerHandle = 0;
let escapeCount = 0;
function checkKeyPressed(evt) {
    if (evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc") {
        clearTimeout(escapeTimerHandle);
        escapeCount++;
        if (escapeCount == 3) {
            window.location.replace("https://classroom.google.com/h");
        } else {
            escapeTimerHandle = setTimeout(function(){
                escapeCount = 0;
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```